# In Java + Linux, what is the correct way to measure latency across CPU cores?

Tags: java, linux, kernel, real-time, benchmarking

I've heard that `System.nanoTime()` is not consistent across CPU cores in Java + Linux. So how can I measure the latency of a one-way message over loopback, in other words, **in the same machine**. The flow is:

- client sends message to server with a timestamp in it
- server gets the message
- servers parses the timestamp out of the message
- servers calculates the one-way latency (now - timestamp)

Note that server and client are running in the same machine but pinned to different cpu cores.

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.nanoTime().  It's only a problem on old OSes such as multi-socket machines running Windows XP.

Within a machine.

- write the timestamp in one thread
- read the timestamp in another thread.

NOTE: Measuring latency this way has serious problems such as co-ordinated omission.  A better approach is

- calculate when a test should start based on a target throughput you want to measure.
- busy wait for that time to be reached if it is not already behind.
- write the time the message should have been sent rather than time actually sent.
- read the timestamp and compare.
- record the distribution.

You can use System.nanoTime() even between machines by doing a round trip test

- send a timestamp
- have the other end send it back.
- compare with the current time.

Comment: Thanks! I find that co-ordinated omission can be overkill. Can't I just time the one-way latency of millions of messages, one at a time (never sending two messages at the same time) and then calculate the average, percentiles, stdev, etc. ?

Comment: @TakeSoUp stddev for latency is meaningless as it doesn't follow a normal distribution. co-ordinated omission is a problem when you are reaching close to your maximum throughput.  If you are say just 10% of maximum it might not be so important. Better to measure it though so you don't have to guess.